# How to import an encrypted sql file in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way to import an encrypted sql file in codeigniter?
This is my code of importing sql file, but i cant do it on encrypted sql file.

```
public function restore()
{
    $templine = '';

    $filename=('C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\warms.sql');

    $lines = file($filename);

    // Loop through each line
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        // Only continue if it's not a comment
        if (substr($line, 0, 2) != '--' && $line != '') {
            // Add this line to the current segment
            $templine .= $line;
            // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
            if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
            // Perform the query
                $this->load->model('Setting_model');
                $this->Setting_model->restore($templine);
                // Reset temp variable to empty
                $templine = '';
            ///////////////


            }
        }
    }
    $msg_info2 ='Database successfully Restored';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_info2',$msg_info2);
}
```

my back-up database looks like these

```
public function back_up(){
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $db_format=array('format'=>'sql','filename'=>'warms_backup.sql',
                    'foreign_key_checks' => FALSE,
        );
    $backup=& $this->dbutil->backup($db_format);
    $encrypt_backup=$this->encrypt->encode($backup);
    $dbname='backup-on-'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql';
    $save='backup/'.$dbname;
    write_file($save,$backup);
    force_download($dbname,$encrypt_backup);
}
```

i encrypted it using codeigniter's library encrypt
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: do you know how it was encrypted?

Comment: i updated my post . i used codeigniter's library encrypt to encrypt the database when my backup is used. The information on my database is very confidential so i want it to be encrypted, but im having trouble on restoring my database becoz of the encryption.